# Prove that the set of all finite sequences of real numbers has the same cardinality as the set $\mathbb{R}$ of reals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that the set of all finite sequences of real numbers has the same cardinality as the set $\mathbb{R}$ of reals.

I can not understand the purpose of the question.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27096/the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-an-infinite-set?rq=1).

Comment: Not really a duplicate -- a finite sequence is not the same as a finite subset, and a priori one could imagine there are more sequences than subsets (since the obvious map from sequences to subsets is surjective but not injective).

Comment: I agree with @hmakholmleftoverMonica. Yet, there is a newer question that covers precisely this question (a bit more general) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696710/cardinality-of-finite-sequences-of-infinite-set/3920798#3920798

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A\sim B$ mean $A,B$ have the same cardinality. You want to show $\cup_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb {R}^n \sim \mathbb {R}.$ Assuming you know that each $\mathbb {R}^n\sim \mathbb {R},$ we can do this: There are bijections from ${R}^n$ to $[n,n+1)$ for each $n$ (because $[n,n+1)\sim \mathbb {R}),$ hence there is a bijection from $\cup_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb {R}^n$ to $[1,\infty) \sim \mathbb {R}.$