# a question about analysis, how to find the largest cardinality in the following examples

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

This is a GRE math question:
[image]

My thoughts: I guess as for the cardinality, (A)=(B) and (D)=(E),but I couldn't prove whether it is true or not. Also, how to find the cardinality of (C), can someone tell me how to analyze this problem? I still have no idea how to find the largest one.

Comment: A, B, D, E all have the same cardinality.

Comment: oh? really,can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

A) The cardinality of $\Bbb{R}$ is just $|\Bbb{R}|$.

B) It is really easy to prove the set is uncountable. Assume it's countable, and use a diagonal argument.

D) D is at least as big as $\Bbb{R}$ since it contains all the singleton sets of elements in $\Bbb{R}$. This question was already solved here: 
[The cardinality of the set of all finite subsets of an infinite set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27096/the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-an-infinite-set)

E) For any infinite set $S$ of some cardinality, the set $S[x]$ has the same cardinality:
[A set and polynomials with coefficients in that set](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_of_Polynomials_over_Infinite_Set_has_Same_Cardinality)

C) has a higher cardinality: [See this paper for a solution of that fact](http://www.math.toronto.edu/vtk/246Winter2011/hw8sol.pdf)

Comment: I cannot see how you have resolved the question. Uncountable sets may have larger or if $\neg$ CH smaller cardinality than $|\mathbb R|$, so you haven't shown that B, for instance, is right or wrong.

Comment: I don't have to show it's true for B because the question only has one correct answer, and that has already been shown to be C.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the cardinality of all functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0;1\}$, one can prove that the corresponding set $C$'s cardinality is strictly greater than that of $\mathbb{R}$ by assuming there is an injective map $f: C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and looking at the map $g: x \mapsto 1 - f^{-1}(x)(x)$, where $f^{-1} \circ f = Id_C$.

$g \in C$ so $g(f(g))$ makes sense, but $g(f(g)) = 1 - f^{-1}(f(g))(f(g)) = 1 - f \circ f^{-1}(g)(f(g)) = 1 - g(f(g)) \neq g(f(g))$, which is impossible. So there can't be an injective map from $C$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

This can be generalized to any set instead of $\mathbb{R}$, though you would have to treat the case of the empty set separately.