# Let $X$ be a topological space and $P$ its infinite subbase. Prove that $ w(X) \leq \operatorname{card}(P) $

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $P$ its infinite subbase. Prove that $ w(X) \leq \operatorname{card}(P) $, where $w(X)$ is the weight of space X i.e. the minimal cardinality of all bases of $X$.

What i thought of:
I would take $B$- a set of all finite intersections of elements of $P$, $B$ is a base of $X$ so $w(X) \leq \operatorname{card}(B)$.

Now it would be great if $\operatorname{card}(B) \leq \operatorname{card}(P)$, but I don't know how to prove it if it's valid. Maybe some set-theory theorem would help.

Comment: Hint: [The cardinality of the set of all finite subsets of an infinite set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27096/the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-an-infinite-set). Notice there is a natural surjection f: the set of finite subsets of a subbase to the set of finite intersections of the elements of the subbase