# Find a cardinality of a particular topology.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If X is an infinite set and a Topology T is defined over it as:

$T = \{ A \subset X \ | \ A = \emptyset \ \lor A^C - finite \}$

How is it possible to find the $card(T)$ above?

I guess one would have to find a bijection to some other set, the cardinality of which is easier to find. But which one?

Comment: This may depend on what $X$ is.

Comment: Edited, I defined X as an infinite set.

Comment: The cardinality of $T$ varies, depending on the cardinality of $X$.

Comment: @GEdgar Of course, but we *can* say $|T| = |X|$.

Comment: I am trying to get CCCP to realize that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is infinite, then the set of finite subsets of $X$ has the same cardinality as $X$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27096/4280)). So the set of complements of finite sets (which is in bijection with the set of finite sets, trivially) also has cardinality $\text{card}(X)$. Adding the singleton $\{\emptyset\}$ to an already infinite set doesn't change that, so the answer is just $|X|$ or $\text{card}(X)$.

Comment: If $X$ is finite, then $T=P(X)$ is just the parts of $X$  ;)

Comment: @N.S. The question states $X$ is infinite.