# drawing n balls randomly, *without* replacement from a bag containing b black balls and w white balls ---Part1

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A bag has $b$ black balls and $w$ white balls. balls of the same color are **indistinguishable**.

1. find, $z_k=$ the number of ways in which $n$ balls can be drawn randomly, *without* replacement from this bag containing $b$ black balls and $w$ white balls, when $k$ of the $n$ balls drawn are white
2. find, $x=$ the number of ways in which $n$ balls can be drawn randomly, *without* replacement from this bag containing $b$ black balls and $w$ white balls

---

**What I have done**

1. There is just one way of drawing $k$ white balls and $n-k$ black balls *without* replacement from this bag containing $b$ black balls and $w$ white balls, ***iff***  $\space k\leq w$ *and* $n-k \leq b$. And there are $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ ways of ordering the $k$ white balls and $n-k$ black balls. So, the number of ways of ordering $n$ balls from a bag of $(w+b)$ balls, when $k$ of the $n$ balls are white is $$z_k = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\mathbb{I}\{k \leq w\}\mathbb{I}\{n-k \leq b\}$$
2. obviously, $$x = \sum_{k=0}^nz_k = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\mathbb{I}\{k<=w\}\mathbb{I}\{n-k<=b\}$$,  where $\mathbb{I}(x) =\begin{cases} 
             1 & x=True \\  
             0 & x=False 
          \end{cases} $.

now, assuming  $n \leq b,n \leq w$, we have,

$$z_k = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$ and $$x = \sum_{k=0}^nz_k = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$

*my question is:* are the calculations done above correct?

**note:-** the current question and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3762205/415432) question are very similar. I know. the question I gave a link to is just too long to answer, I guess. So, I am trying to break down my question into small pieces so that they can be answered easily. I will change/delete the question(that I gave a link to) based on whether there is a mistake in the calculations done in this question.

**edit:-** the follow-up question to this question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3763089/415432)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks good to me. A quick way to check your work would be to solve the problem another way. For example, provided there are enough balls of each color, each of the $n$ balls you draw can be either of two options (black or white), thus there are $2^n$ many ways to draw them, agreeing with your answer.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: thanks for verifying! could you please answer the follow-up question to this question too. The follow-up question is here--->https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3763089/415432

Comment: Hey!  I would like to let you know that [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744896/is-there-a-bijection-between-an-infinite-set-e-and-big-fe-to-mathbbz-b) has been reopened, and I am inviting you to put your answer there in your own separate answer.  (Feel free to remove your answer from my post.)